# How will the coordinator be removed with Nectar's implementation?

Tags: iota-network, coordicide

Will it be removed in the same way that it was removed from the current testnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on how the current testnet behaves. The testnet is there to learn about the current coordicide implementation and to detect whether there are any unnoticed flaws in its algorithms. If it works fine, it may remain unchanged. But probably there will be some changes before Coordicide reaches Nectar stage, and maybe others before it is implemented on the mainnet.

Answer (score 2):

It is not removed, it does not exist there in the first place. It runs from the start without coordinator.